# How to exclude all up-volume days from the previous 10 days?

Tags: pine-script

Trying to write a Tradingview pine editor script that plots a Pocket pivot i.e. The volume of the pocket pivot day should be higher than the largest down-volume of the last 10 trading days.

I have been so far been able to get the largest volume of the last 10 trading days. But this includes both up and down volume days. I need only down volume days in the previous 10 days. Can anyone please help me exclude all up-volume days from the previous 10 days?

```
study(title=“Pocket Pivot”, shorttitle=“PP”, precision=0,overlay =true) 

pp= volume > highest(nz(volume[1]), 9) 

plotshape(series=pp, title=“Pocket Pivot”, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.navy, transp=0, size=size.tiny)
```

Answer (score 0):

finallynitin

Does the below script help with your question?

[https://uk.tradingview.com/script/MEWNodEK-Pivot-OBV-Reset-LM/][1]